# Bluetooth in Debian 11 doesn't work

Tags: linux, debian, bluetooth

I installed Debian 11, and the bluetooth doesn't work.

When I run the command `sudo systemctl status bluetooth`, the bluetooth is shown as active. But when I go to configurations it shows this:

the message in portuguese is: "bluetooth not found"
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

my hardware:

```
ramon@dell:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 02)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
```

the command: lsusb; sudo dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0cf3:e005 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1bcf:28c0 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1532:006e Razer USA, Ltd DeathAdder Essential
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0951:16dd Kingston Technology HyperX Alloy Core RGB
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[sudo] senha para ramon:
[    0.281035] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    2.086373] i915 0000:00:02.0: firmware: failed to load i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (-2)
[    2.086376] firmware_class: See https://wiki.debian.org/Firmware for information about missing firmware
[    2.086379] i915 0000:00:02.0: Direct firmware load for i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin failed with error -2
[    2.086381] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Failed to load DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin. Disabling runtime power management.
[    2.086382] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] DMC firmware homepage: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/i915
[    4.516681] platform regulatory.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware regulatory.db
[    4.516799] platform regulatory.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware regulatory.db.p7s
[    4.957804] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.957836] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.957840] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.957842] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.957847] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.006973] usb 1-8: firmware: failed to load ar3k/AthrBT_0x31010100.dfu (-2)
[    5.007015] usb 1-8: Direct firmware load for ar3k/AthrBT_0x31010100.dfu failed with error -2
[    5.007025] Bluetooth: Loading patch file failed
[    5.543212] r8169 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load rtl_nic/rtl8106e-1.fw (-2)
[    5.543919] r8169 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for rtl_nic/rtl8106e-1.fw failed with error -2
[    5.543953] r8169 0000:02:00.0: Unable to load firmware rtl_nic/rtl8106e-1.fw (-2)
[    6.378699] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    6.378706] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    6.378710] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Comment: That the service is running it only means the module is installed, it doesn't follow the hardware is properly recognized with the necessary drivers. Please [edit] the4 question and IDENTIFY your hardware. Run either `lspci` (for internal) or `lsusb` (for external, USB) in order to identify the hardware.

Comment: ok! what do you think about that?

Comment: Please DON'T post images of command outputs! Now, from what we can see already you're using a miniPCIe WiFi+Bluetooth card. Those work for both if, and only if, the slot has USB lanes as well as PCI lanes. Typically the USB lanes are absent in miniPCs ann similar hardware and that seems to be the case here. If all the required lanes were there it would simply work, end of story.

Comment: In conclusion: You may want to use a cheap USB Bluetooth dongle instead.

Comment: but why? The bluetooth runs in unbuntu. I havent another way?

Comment: "WHY" I just told you. Please read again. And no, it *may* show up in Ubuntu but that doesn't mean it works...

Comment: @ChanganAuto You're wrong – Ramon says the hardware works on a different OS. So, while I generally would ask you to be a bit less aggressive, please also read the replies you're getting precisely.

Comment: Sorry, the english is not my language. I only wanna know if the problem is my computer(hardware) or the problem is the OS.

Comment: @RamonJales you just said the same hardware works with a different OS, right?

Comment: (and also, Changan is right: a screenshot is much worse than copy and pasted output of `lspci`)

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes! When i used mint or unbuntu the bluetooth worked

Comment: Please edit to add results for `lsusb; sudo dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Comment: How did it work? Were you able to pair BT devices and use then as expected? Or was it the case of the BT appearing in the settings and you assuming it was working? Such clarifications are better poested as edits to the original question rather than comments.

Comment: @RamonJales good news: then it's not the hardware :) You might be missing firmware

Comment: Yes! @ChanganAuto. With this same computer i used bluetooth. Today, i installed debian , and the bluetooth doesnt work

Comment: @MarcusMüller How can i install this firmware?

Comment: That being the case please do as requested above by @Jeremy31 and please do [edit] your question with the results code fenced, not a screenshot.

Comment: according to your `dmesg` output, you have working bluetooth hardware, so not even firmware is missing. I still can't read the screenshot, so nobody can help you until you replace your screenshot of `lspci` with the text from `lspci`

Comment: @MarcusMüller ok! I edit my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, this makes sense:

> 01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

and

> ```
> 5.006973] usb 1-8: firmware: failed to load ar3k/AthrBT_0x31010100.dfu (-2)
> 5.007015] usb 1-8: Direct firmware load for ar3k/AthrBT_0x31010100.dfu failed with error -2
> ```

You've installed the wifi firmware, but you're missing the full Bluetooth firmware for the AR9565.

You need to `sudo apt install firmware-atheros` and reboot.

Comment: i tried run the command, but doesnt work. The terminal show this message: "E: Unable to find package firmware-atheros"

Comment: You might need to enable "non-free" or "non-free-firmware" in your sources list. Which one depends on your debian version, see https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=atheros

Comment: Thanks so much! Its running!